# How to apply mobile number pattern on UITextField in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, regex, string

I need to get user mobile phone number in **Persian** and **English**.
And apply the phone number pattern to show.
**I found two solutions**, each of them has a **problem**.

Number 1:

```
extension String{
    func applyPatternOnNumbers(pattern: String) -> String {
        let  replacmentCharacter: Character = "#"
        var pure = self.replacingOccurrences( of: "[^۰-۹0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
        for index in 0 ..< pattern.count {
            guard index < pure.count else { return pure }
            let stringIndex = String.Index.init(encodedOffset: index)
            let patternCharacter = pattern[stringIndex]
            guard patternCharacter != replacmentCharacter else { continue }
            pure.insert(patternCharacter, at: stringIndex)
        }
       return pure
    }
 }
```

use in editingChanged

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    let textField = UITextField()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: 300, height: 50)
        textField.delegate = self
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
        self.view.addSubview(textField)
    }

    @objc func editingChanged(){
        let pattern = "+# (###) ###-####"
        let mobile = textField.text
        textField.text = mobile!.applyPatternOnNumbers(pattern: pattern)
    }
}
```

When the number is typed in English for example +1800444777
the result is
`// +1 (800) 444-7777`

But when the Persian numbers are typed for example +۱۸۰۰۴۴۴۷۷۷
the result is this 
`// +۱ (۸۩ ´۷۷۷`

Number 2:

```
extension String{
      func applyPatternOnNumbers(pattern: String) -> String {
           let replacmentCharacter: Character = "#"
           let pureNumber = self.replacingOccurrences( of: "[^۰-۹0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
           var result = ""
           var pureNumberIndex = pureNumber.startIndex
           for patternCharacter in pattern {
               if patternCharacter == replacmentCharacter {
               guard pureNumberIndex < pureNumber.endIndex else { return result }
               result.append(pureNumber[pureNumberIndex])
               pureNumber.formIndex(after: &pureNumberIndex)
               } else {
                 result.append(patternCharacter)
               }
            }
        return result
     }
}
```

use this method is the same as the previous method
This method works in both English and Persian

**English** "+1800444777" result is // `+1 (800) 444-7777`
**Persian** "+۱۸۰۰۴۴۴۷۷۷" result is // `+۱ (۸۰۰) ۴۴۴-۷۷۷۷`

**But the problem is** `space` & `-` , `(` , `)` , `+` chars **can not to be removed** on editing the `textfield`

Comment: I can recommend PhoneNumberKit if you don't mind using an additional framework for this task

Comment: Using `String.Index.init(encodedOffset:)` in Number 1 is wrong. Your `editingChanged()` does not compile again. Why do you stubbornly refuse to show your actual code? You would not get the right solution until you show the real code you are using.

Comment: For the second example, (number 2), could you please add an example of input, expected output, and real (failing) output?

Comment: @OOPer there is actual code, Using `String.Index.init(encodedOffset:) ` is no difference in run, The `editingChange` event is not my problem and it's happening at any time during typing.

Comment: @Julio in number 2, the input is the same as number 1 but can't delete any characters except numbers during editing

Comment: @amin, please do not type. Copy your actual code, and paste the lines into the editing pane, please do not edit your code in the editing pane, a small mis-typing would affect the detailed behavior, so that you cannot get the right solution.

Comment: @amin, now your updated `ViewController` compiles, how nice! And I can see the behavior and understood what you were trying to say. Writing an answer, wait a minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please replace the Number 2 extension to the following:

```
extension String{
    func applyPatternOnNumbers(pattern: String) -> String {
        let replacmentCharacter: Character = "#"
        let pureNumber = self.replacingOccurrences( of: "[^۰-۹0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
        var result = ""
        var pureNumberIndex = pureNumber.startIndex
        for patternCharacter in pattern {
            guard pureNumberIndex < pureNumber.endIndex else { return result }
            if patternCharacter == replacmentCharacter {
                result.append(pureNumber[pureNumberIndex])
                pureNumber.formIndex(after: &pureNumberIndex)
            } else {
                result.append(patternCharacter)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

This updated code checks if `pureNumberIndex` getting at the end or not, a little earlier that the former version.

With this change, the `pattern` needs to end with `replacmentCharacter`. I hope all the patterns you have listed up end with `"#"`.

Comment: For this question, I asked three questions in different ways
And you were in two places, really thank you

Comment: @amin, please remember one thing. Sometimes easily verifiable code tells us much more than hundreds of words. Better read this article carefully [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I hope I can help you sooner if there's next chance.